# DiscordJS scraping MAL

Tags: web-scraping, discord.js

So I made a function to scrape this anime top list "https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php" and successfully did it, so in "https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php" you can see 50 top animes but I only did 10 so that **discord.js** embed wont reach the characters limit but I also want to show the other 11-50 animes also by 10 like page 1 of the embed is 1-10 the page 2 of the embed is page 11-20 and so on that's what I want, I did is a slashComamnd that you can check the page manually */top (number/page)* and I also did a button to click and that's when I stop the button didn't work when clicking the button the embed wont edit/update BUT when you use */top (number/page)* and click the "previous" button it will update BUT when */top (5 or 4, or 3)* it update to page 1 instead of the previous page not to the very top page and also when clicking next button it won't work too neither using or without using the command */top (number/page)* im sorry im really bad at explaning things... i tried

this is my code:

````
  const { EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle,  ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');
  const { scrapeTopAnime } = require('../../config/topPage');
  
  module.exports = {
      command_data: {
          name: 'top',
          description: 'Give you the Top 10 Anime ',
          type: 1,
          options: [
            {
              name: 'page',
              description: 'Enter what page to see',
              type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Number,
              required: false
            }
          ],
      },
      role_perms: null,
      developers_only: false,
      owner_only: false,
      cooldown: 5,
      logger: true,
      category: "Information",
      run: async (client, interaction) => {
  
        try {
          await interaction.deferReply()
          
          let page = interaction.options.getNumber("page") || 1;
          const topAnimeList = await scrapeTopAnime(page);
  
          const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
              new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('top_previous')
                .setLabel('Previous')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
                .setEmoji('⬅️')
                .setDisabled(page == 1), // Disable the button if it's the first page
              new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('top_next')
                .setLabel('Next')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
                .setEmoji('➡️')
                .setDisabled(page == 5) // Disable the button if it's the last page
              );
    
          const topEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Top 10 Anime (MAL)')
            .setColor('#FF0000')
            .setDescription('Here are the top 10 anime:')
    
          topAnimeList.forEach((anime) => {
            topEmbed.addFields(
              { name: `${anime.rank}. ${anime.title}`, value: `Score: ${anime.score}`, inline: false }
            );
          });
  
        const message = await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [topEmbed], components: [row] });
  
          const filter = i => i.customId === 'top_previous' || i.customId === 'top_next';
          const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 60000 }); // Collect for 60 seconds
  
          collector.on('collect', async i => {
            let currentPage = parseInt(i.message.embeds[0].title.split(' ')[3]);
  
            let newPage;
  
            if (i.customId === 'top_previous') {
              newPage = currentPage - 1;
              console.log(`Previous button clicked, new page is ${newPage}`);
            } else if (i.customId === 'top_next') {
              newPage = currentPage + 1;
              console.log(`Next button clicked, new page is ${newPage}`);
            }
  
            const topAnimeList = await scrapeTopAnime(newPage);
            console.log(`Scraped ${topAnimeList.length} anime from page ${newPage}`);
            const topEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle(`Top 10 Anime (MAL) Page ${newPage}`)
      .setColor('#FF0000')
      .setDescription('Here are the top 10 anime:');
  
          topAnimeList.forEach((anime) => {
            topEmbed.addFields(
        { name: `${anime.rank}. ${anime.title}`, value: `Score: ${anime.score}`, inline: false }
      );
          });

          const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
    .addComponents(
      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('previous')
        .setLabel('Previous')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
        .setEmoji('⬅️')
        .setDisabled(newPage == 1),
      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('next')
        .setLabel('Next')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
        .setEmoji('➡️')
        .setDisabled(newPage == 5)
    );

  // Update the message with the new embed and action row
  await i.update({ embeds: [topEmbed], components: [row] });
          });
          collector.on('end', collected => {
  console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} interactions`);
  // 
});
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
          const errorEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('An error occurred')
            .setDescription('```' + e + '```')
            .setColor(0xe32424);
  
          interaction.editReply({ embeds: [errorEmbed] });
        }
      }
  };
````

and this is the code/function for scraping

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

async function scrapeTopAnime(page) {
  const url = `https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?limit=${(page - 1) * 10}`;
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
  const topAnimeList = [];

  $('.ranking-list').each((index, element) => {
    if (index < 10) {
      const rank = $(element).find('.rank').text().trim();
      const title = $(element).find('.title').text().trim();
      const score = $(element).find('.score').text().trim();
      topAnimeList.push({ rank, title, score });
    }
  });

  return topAnimeList;
}

module.exports = {
  scrapeTopAnime,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let titleParts = b.message.embeds[0].title.split(' ');
let currentPage = parseInt(titleParts[titleParts.length - 1]);
```